# change color of button when carousel slide linked to it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel and a range of buttons on top it which represent certain services provided by an organization. I am trying to achieve 2 things here:

1. (This one is done) When user clicks on button A, then slide linked to button A appears and the color of button A changes indicating that its active.
2. (Having problem here) When slide A changes from slide B or whichever, then color of button A (which is linked to slide A) should automatically change indicating that its respective slide has been clicked.

As you can see in this image, when button clicked it turns blue and slide linked to it appears
[image: when button clicked, it turns blue and slide]

But here, when I change the slide by using next/prev controllers, buttons are not activated
[image]

This is what my code looks like

```
    <nav1>
        <ul class="nav1">
            <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="image1"></a>
            <h4>Analytics & <br> Optimization</li>

            <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="1" class="image2"></a>
            <h4>Design<br> Services</h4></li>

            <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="2" class="image4"></a>
            <h4>Web & Mobile<br> Technology</h4></li>

            <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="3" class="image3"></a>
            <h4>Online <br> Marketing</h4></li>

            <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="4" class="image5"></a>
            <h4>Cyber<br> Security</h4></li>

            <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="5" class="image6"></a>
            <h4>Digital<br> Transformation</h4></li>
        </ul>
    </nav1>

    <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">    
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">     
    <div class="item active">
            <div class="clearfix"><img class="img2" src="assets/images/analysis.png">
        </div>  
          </div>
</div>
```

so on..

Style:

```
  .nav1 a:active, .nav1 a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #8C9EFF;
  background: #80D8FF;
}
```

I believe its got to do with slide.bs function but I am not able to figure out how!

Comment: Your class isn't being activated when you hit the next/prev controls as they aren't included the styles you have for the links/buttons. You need to modify your css to include the controls or add an active class on click to the respective button with JS. I can help more when I get home, I am on my phone right now

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging the question @Orlando, what is it that I should do?

Comment: do you want to use javascript or CSS? using CSS might take some reworking of your html

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript example. This is limited as I don't have all the code.

Your going to tie into the slide action of the carousel then find the correct instance of the image class and add the active class to it and find the one with the active class already and remove it.

```
`$('#myCarousel1').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (event) {
    var nextactiveslide = $(event.relatedTarget).index();
    var $btns = $(".nav1");
    var $active = $btns.find("[data-slide-to='" + nextactiveslide + "']");
    $btns.find("div[class^='image']").removeClass("active");
    $active.find("div[class^='image']").addClass("active");
});`
```

Note the orginal solution came from [How to change customized carousel indicator background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425382/how-to-change-customized-carousel-indicator-background-color) I just modified it to use your classes and IDs.