# how to customize bootstrap carousel indicators ' - ' color

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

i searched all over the Google and bootstrap documentaries but could not make out how do we change the ' - ' color
The most i was able to find was this [How to change customized carousel indicator background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425382/how-to-change-customized-carousel-indicator-background-color/26430452)
but it changes the background of the indicators and a box type shape is formed
how do we change the '- ' color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.carousel-indicators li
{
      background-color: #000 !important;
       /*more custom style*/
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: grey !important;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp